# How to convert a function that returns a int to a function that returns a bool using boost::bind?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I have something like the following:

```
 struct A{
  virtual int derp(){ 
      if(herp()) return 1; 
      else return 0; 
   }
  void slurp(){
    boost::function<bool(int x, int y)> purp = /** boost bind derp to match lvalue sig  **/;
  }
 }
```

Any ideas? I want to create the function prup which basically calls derp and ignores the (x,y) passed in.

I need something like

```
bool purp(int x, int y){ return derp(); }
```

but want to avoid creating it as a member function, and rather just create it locally if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If C++11 is available, consider using a lambda. Otherwise, you can use Boost.Lambda:

```
boost::function<bool(int x, int y)> purp = !!boost::lambda::bind(&A::derp, this);
```

That uses the standard conversion of `int` to `bool`.

If you want a specific return value of `A::derp` to be `true`, then use `==`. For example, suppose you want a return value of 3 to be `true`:

```
boost::function<bool(int x, int y)> purp = boost::lambda::bind(&A::derp, this) == 3;
```

**EDIT:** Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

struct A {
    virtual int derp() {
        std::cout << "within A::derp()\n";
        return 0;
    }
    void slurp() {
        boost::function<bool(int x, int y)> purp = !!boost::lambda::bind(&A::derp, this);
        std::cout << (purp(3, 14) ? "true" : "false") << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.slurp();
}
```

Outputs:

```
within A::derp()
false
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure about the boost::bind library and how to handle your case, but if you have a C++ enabled environment you can use a lambda in place of the bind:

```
auto purp = [=](int,int) -> bool { return derp(); };
// alternatively:
//std::function<bool(int,int)> purp = [](int,int)->bool{return derp();};
```

With lambda support suddenly bind does not seem like such a great tool :)

Comment: You need to capture `this`: `[=](int, int) -> bool { return derp(); };`

Comment: @DanielTrebbien: Correct, I was not paying attention to the rest of the code and missed that `derp` is a member function not a free function.

Answer (score 1):

```
boost::function<bool(int x, int y)> purp = boost::bind(&A::derp, this);
```

This should work as long as `derp` return value is implicitly convertible to `bool`. You will get this annoying warning with VC++ though: `"warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)"`

Answer (score 0):

Boolean true/false is just an integer in C implementations already and you could certainly write something to do this.  I do not understand the point of doing this or why the function is contained in a struct.  The main question is why would you want a function to take parameters so they can be ignored ?  Why not have the function return a bool instead of an int ?